# Get the closest date if it doesn't exist in the inputted date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im doing a backend now, and I'm trying to make a list of number of rooms by date range.

**DB Structure**

```
id room_type_id room_count date_applied
1  1            2          2011-09-01
1  1            3          2011-09-05
1  1            1          2011-09-06
```

**In the HTML:**

If the user inputted 
From: **2011-Sept-01** 
To: **2011-Sept-06**. 
This would be the display. (This is already OK)

```
Date          Room Count
2011-Sept-1   2
2011-Sept-2   2
2011-Sept-3   2
2011-Sept-4   2
2011-Sept-5   3
2011-Sept-6   1
```

And my problem now is that, when the user inputted into From and To is already out of range from the data stored in the database. Sample: From: 2011-09-07 To: 2011-09-09

The Output should be displayed in the HTML should be look like this.

```
Date          Room Count
2011-Sept-7   1
2011-Sept-8   1
2011-Sept-9   1
```

It will get the closest/last data in the database. For this sample it would be **2011-09-06**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: should it look only for the closer date in relation to the lower date only? or also for the upper date?

Comment: it will only look for the closest lower date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you may need to run a sub query finding the immediate lowest date? and then start from that date to the end date.

Forexample.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN (SELECT date FROM tbl WHERE date < lower_range LIMIT 1 ) AND upper_range
```